# How to prevent creating additional folder if destination folder exists while copying file using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy a folder from the local computer to a remote server. It works but if the destination folder already exists it is creating a duplicate folder inside it.

```
copy-item -Path C:\test -Destination \\server\F$\testpassed -recurse -Force
```

Comment: just files and not the whole test folder again

Comment: Oops, deleted my question by accident! So the above comment doesn't seem weird, I was asking if it was the folder or the files within it that need to be copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy only the files from within `C:\test` to the `\\server\F$\testpassed` folder you need to use the following command:

```
Copy-Item -Path C:\test\* -Destination \\server\F$\testpassed -Recurse
```

`\*` is a wildcard for anything within the folder, and will cause `Copy-Item` to copy anything *within* the folder to the Destination. You could also use `*.txt` to only copy txt files if you wanted only a specific file type to be copied.

---

**EDIT:**

I would test for the presence of `$TARGETDIR` and then create it if needed. This way you only have a single copy command.

```
$TargetDir = "\\server\F$\testpassed"
$SourceDir = "C:\test"

if(!(Test-Path -Path $TARGETDIR)) {New-Item -Path $TARGETDIR -ItemType Directory}

Copy-Item -Path "$SourceDir\*" -Destination $TARGETDIR -Recurse
```

Comment: Thanks James. Actually i wanted to copy only files if folder already exists. I put your suggestion in following condition and it works perfectly.    if(!(Test-Path -Path $TARGETDIR ))
{
 copy-item -Path C:\test -Destination $TARGETDIR -recurse 
    
}
else
{
   copy-item -Path C:\test\* -Destination $TARGETDIR -recurse -Force
}

Comment: @PratikBompilwar see my edit for how I would do this.

Comment: @PratikBompilwar feel free to mark as answered if you're happy with my answer :)

Comment: @PratikBompilwar You need to click the grey checkmark/tick to the left of my question to do this.

Comment: Just did it.Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Using source path in below way will solve your issue

Copy-Item -Path C:\test*

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $Source = Get-childitem C:\test -Recurse

copy-item -Path $Source.FullName -Destination C:\temp -recurse -Force
```

Use GC to stop getting the folder as well as the contents.

Comment: Thanks for the  response Richard, but by running above code now it is not at all copying files.